# Re-usable function

Tags: python, function

I am using Python for some operations on a XML file.
Because I am new to programming I would like to know how I can re-use the snippet below, currently it has a hard-coded statement in it.

Please look at the line with

```
for ERPRecord in aroot.iter('part'):
```

inside it, aroot should be replaced with the modular option or variable.

```
def SetERP(ArticleN,ERPn):
    for ERPRecord in aroot.iter('part'):
        if ERPRecord.get('P_ARTICLE_ORDERNR') == ArticleN:
            ERPRecord.set('P_ARTICLE_ERPNR', ERPn)
```

I would like to have a function without hard-coded parts in so it is able to be used again in other projects. My best guess is that the sequence "aroot" will be replaced by a variable like this:

```
    def SetERP(ArticleN,ERPn, XMLroot):
        for ERPRecord in XMLroot.iter('part'):
            if ERPRecord.get('P_ARTICLE_ORDERNR') == ArticleN:
                ERPRecord.set('P_ARTICLE_ERPNR', ERPn)
```

Any advice on this would be welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define aroot as a parameter, so you would have to pass your root in every time you call the function, if that is what you mean?

```
def SetERP(ArticleN, ERPn, aroot):
    for ERPRecord in aroot.iter('part'):
        if ERPRecord.get('P_ARTICLE_ORDERNR') == ArticleN:
            ERPRecord.set('P_ARTICLE_ERPNR', ERPn)
```

Comment: This could be the option, did not know that they passed the sequence as an argument. Thanks!

Comment: Who is 'they' I thought you wrote that function?